# PHP or Javascript Timer?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, timer

Hi all I am really asking a more of a theoretical question here - but I am creating an application which is kind of like a true false answers webpage using PHP and have found that I now require the use of a timer. I am using MVC (codeigniter) and reload the controller when the user goes to the next question. I was wondering if you guys have any ideas of the best way to implement a timer - I can't put this on the page in JS as I assume that the timer will restart and haven't found a way of doing this in php. Is there a best practice I am missing like another controller to just perform the timer? - I apologise if this is a truly stupid question as I said its not really a coding issue yet more of a theoretical - I am also a complete beginner so please have patience

Comment: Do it on both sides - _JavaScript_ to re-load, _PHP_ to prevent people reloading faster than they should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the starting time in PHP and put it in a $_SESSION variable. after that give it to javascript to countdown/countup  each page. even if the user manipulate your js timer, you'll know how much time has really passed in php

sample code:
in your first page, where you start your quiz:

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['startTime'] = time(); ?>
```

and now in other pages:

```
<?php session_start();
$timePassed = time() - $_SESSION['startTime']; // pass it back to javascript
?>
```

Comment: you beauty I could kiss you, this was exactly the kind of thing I was looking for thank-you very much!

Comment: upvote/accept if this answer helped you, so other could use this too ;)

Comment: The user can still manipulate the session though. You should store the start time in a database or a text file (using the session_id to auth the user), and then check from that.

Comment: how could the user manipulate the session without hacking into your server?

Comment: You can use ajax to change  next question then after each click you can use setInterval in java script to handle timeout for your page easily